# button click is not working in mobile on single attempt with settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

On click of `<a>` tag I am calling one function which is internally calling another function on `setTimeout` with 100 ms delay.

So on click of `<a>` tag it will open list of items for ex. **list a**.
now I am applying some filters and trying to open list again, due to this filter I should get another list for ex. **list b**.

In web application this code is working fine and showing **list b** but in mobile application on click of `<a>` it is showing **list a** on first time click and if I click again on `<a>` then it is showing updated list i.e **list b**

Issue is - It should display **list b** on click of `<a>` on first click not on second click.
(Both IOS and android)

**JS**

```
function showList(){
    setTimeout(function(){anotherList(); }, 100);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showList();" data-toggle="dropdown" id="selectListBtn">Select List</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into an issue, with hooking into the ["touch"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) events, on a mobile device.

If you are using JQuery you may want to try:

```
$('#selectListBtn').on('click touchstart', function () {...}
```

Or this:

```
$('#selectListBtn').on('click touch', function () {...}
```

MDN has great content, on [using touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events).

Also, just a small suggestion, check out this [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting), on the merits of avoiding inline javascript